# Build fails resolving Objectify dependency

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, objectify

I'm trying to add Objectify to my Google App Engine project.  I followed the instructions at https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/MavenRepository which says to add a dependency to my pom.xml.

I copied and pasted the dependency into my pom.xml but I got the following error when I executed `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.796 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-06T15:34:45-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project nbsocialmetrics-frontend: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.netbase.nbsocialmetrics:nbsocialmetrics-frontend:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:jar:check for latest version: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:jar:check for latest version: Could not transfer artifact com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:pom:check for latest version from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 76: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/check for latest version/objectify-check for latest version.pom -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :nbsocialmetrics-frontend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to copy and paste and then to modify the version number.  Here is the original dependency as written at https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/MavenRepository:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>check for latest version</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

What I failed to notice was the string of text "check for latest version".  So I clicked on http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.googlecode.objectify%22 and was then able to see the latest version, at this time, is 5.1.1.

So I entered this into my pom.xml instead and then `mvn clean install` worked:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```